# Listing all files in directory with .bar extenion but not .foo.bar extension

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ls

I want to use the `ls` command to list all files in directory a with `.bar` extension but not `.foo.bar` extension.  The following picks up `.foo.bar` files which I don't want

```
ls -l some/path/*.js
```

Must be simple.  I just need an AND and NOT in there somehow.

Comment: What that `*.js` doing there?

Comment: What about a file names `x.y.bar`? Do you want that to be listed or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `bash` pathname expansion with `[` pattern matching, you can write:

```
ls -l some/path/*[!(.foo)].bar
```

Comment: How do we modify it if `foo` is replaced by any other word?

Comment: You can replace `.foo` by anything else you want (except a pipe `|`). Simply keep the parenthesis.

Comment: This will not list out file with .bar for names containing the a character followed by just f, just fo, just foo, just o, just oo. bar like afoo.bar, o.bar, oo.bar, foo.bar, cf.bar ...

Comment: +1 This requires the `extglob` shell option to be on: `shopt -s extglob`

Answer (score 1):

```
find -name '*.bar' -not -name '*.foo.bar'
```

Comment: Will fail if there is a .foo in the middle like a.foo.b.bar... maybe `-not -name '*.foo.bar'` is a better fit.

Comment: @another.anon.coward, this is suposed to be a help site not a spoon feeding one, I'm sure that the author would be able to adapt to his/her needs

Comment: Pls don't mind my spoon feeding but shouldn't it be: `find . -name '*.bar' -not -name '*.foo.bar'`. +1 however for suggesting good use of -not option in find.

Comment: @anubhava: When you don't provide the path for searching, current directory is assumed. I tend to use the form which Sorin has used for finding in current directory

Comment: @Sorin: I was just making an observation thats all! ^^

Comment: @another.anon.coward `find -name '*.bar'` gives error on my Mac.

Comment: @anubhava: Ah sorry! No exp on Mac ):... works nicely on Linux though (at least on Ubuntu & FC which I have used)

Answer (score 1):

If your request is to match ab.js and cd.js but not ef.tk.js, then you can use the following code. It solves 2 problems:

- no problem with space in the path or the filenames (ex: files are in '/var/tmp/my dir')
- no problem with dots in the path name (ex: files are in /var/tmp/my.dir)

If 'DIR' is the directory where you want to find your files, and 'EXT' is the pattern you try to match, use:

```
find DIR  -regex '.*/[^./]*\.PAT' -print0 | xargs -0 -r ls -l
```

For example, if DIR is '/var/tmp' and PAT is 'js' (for *.js) :

```
find /var/tmp -regex '.*/[^./]*\.js' -print0 | xargs -0 -r ls -l
```

This solution works if the target directory is '/var/tmp/my dir' (don't forget to put the directory inside quotes then or escape the space)

If you have many files, you may run into command-line length limitation. Then you might consider using 'xargs -0 -L XXX ls -l' instead, so each invokation of ls will be only with XXX max files (eg use 500 for XXX).

Comment: Will fail if file name has more than one `.` like `a.b.js`

Comment: Isn't that the point ? The asker wants to match a.js but not a.b.js. That's what this does (did you try it?)

Comment: Added '-r' flag to xargs, to prevent it from running 'ls -l' if no file is found by 'find' (in this case, it would have listed the current directory, not good...)

Comment: Sorry for the flood... Consider adding '-maxdepth 1' before '-regex' if you don't want to search into sub-directories of DIR

Comment: Umm not really(at least from what I can understand) the q is more like if you have a.b.js & x.y.js, listing is needed ending with .js but not .y.js so of the 2 files only a.b.js should be displayed

Comment: OK, I see now. The q was not very clear, I tried to solve a more complicated problem! I guess you're right. That's why I had written at first "If your request is to match ab.js and cd.js but not ef.tk.js...".

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked how to do this in bash, but in `zsh` you could do

```
ls -l *.bar~*.foo.bar
```

And you would get all `.bar` files that are not named `.foo.bar`. I guess it's *another* reason to move to `zsh` :)